# How to sort a property in arrays in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array and it has multiple arrays of rates, I want to sort on the property floating

This is I am trying

```
let newArrayRates = [];
newArrayRates = banksData;

newArrayRates.forEach(element => {
    element.rates.sort(function(a,b){

        element.rates.sort(function(a, b) {

            let textA = a; 
            let textB = b;

            return textA.floating <
                textB.floating
                ? -1
                : textA.floating >
                textB.floating
                ? 1 
                : 0;

    })
```

This is the array to sort by Property floating

```
var banksData =[ 
   { 
      "name":"ANZ2",
      "rates":[ 
         { 
            "bankName":"ANZ",
            "productName":"ANZ",
            "floating":6.9,
            "sixMonths":4.79,
            "oneYear":4.15,
            "eighteenMonths":4.49,
            "twoYears":4.09,
            "threeYears":4.49,
            "fourYears":4.75,
            "fiveYears":4.85,
            "sixYears":0.0,
            "revolvingCredit":5.8,
            "isSpecial":false
         },
         { 
            "bankName":"ANZ Bank",
            "productName":"ANZ Special",
            "floating":2.0,
            "sixMonths":4.29,
            "oneYear":3.65,
            "eighteenMonths":3.99,
            "twoYears":3.59,
            "threeYears":3.99,
            "fourYears":0.0,
            "fiveYears":0.0,
            "sixYears":0.0,
            "revolvingCredit":0.0,
            "isSpecial":true
         }
      ],
      "knownDiscount":[ 

      ],
      "type":[ 
         1,
         4
      ],
      "mortgageFeatures":{ 
         "welcomeHomeLoans":"No",
         "kiwiBuild":"Yes",
         "preApproval":"Up to 90 days",
         "interestOnly":"Yes",
         "redraw":"No",
         "revolvingCredit":"Yes",
         "amortisingRevolvingCredit":"No",
         "revolvingCreditMonthlyFee":"$12.50",
         "offset":"No",
         "ownerOccupiedLoanTerm":"30 Years",
         "investmentPropertyLoanTerm":"30 Years",
         "earlyRepayment":"Yes"
      },
      "url":"/banks/ANZ2",
      "website":"https://www.anz.co.nz/personal/"
   },
   { 
      "name":"ASB ",
      "rates":[ 
         { 
            "bankName":"ASB1",
            "productName":"ASB",
            "floating":5.2,
            "sixMonths":4.79,
            "oneYear":4.15,
            "eighteenMonths":4.25,
            "twoYears":4.09,
            "threeYears":4.39,
            "fourYears":4.69,
            "fiveYears":4.79,
            "sixYears":0.0,
            "revolvingCredit":5.3,
            "isSpecial":false
         },
         { 
            "bankName":"ASB Bank",
            "productName":"ASB Special",
            "floating":5.0,
            "sixMonths":4.29,
            "oneYear":3.75,
            "eighteenMonths":3.75,
            "twoYears":3.59,
            "threeYears":3.89,
            "fourYears":4.19,
            "fiveYears":4.29,
            "sixYears":0.0,
            "revolvingCredit":0.0,
            "isSpecial":true
         }
      ],
      "knownDiscount":[ 

      ],
      "type":[ 
         1,
         4
      ],
      "mortgageFeatures":{ 
         "welcomeHomeLoans":"No",
         "kiwiBuild":"Yes",
         "preApproval":"Up to 90 days",
         "interestOnly":"Yes",
         "redraw":"No",
         "revolvingCredit":"Yes",
         "amortisingRevolvingCredit":"Yes",
         "revolvingCreditMonthlyFee":"$12.00",
         "offset":"No",
         "ownerOccupiedLoanTerm":"30 years",
         "investmentPropertyLoanTerm":"25 years",
         "earlyRepayment":"Yes"
      },
      "url":"/banks/ASB ",
      "website":"https://www.asb.co.nz/"
   },
   { 
      "name":"BNZ",
      "rates":[ 
         { 
            "bankName":"BNZ",
            "productName":"BNZ Owner Occupied Standard",
            "floating":5.3,
            "sixMonths":4.79,
            "oneYear":4.45,
            "eighteenMonths":4.55,
            "twoYears":4.35,
            "threeYears":4.55,
            "fourYears":4.95,
            "fiveYears":5.15,
            "sixYears":0.0,
            "revolvingCredit":0.0,
            "isSpecial":false
         },
         { 
            "bankName":"BNZ",
            "productName":"BNZ Owner Occupied Special",
            "floating":0.0,
            "sixMonths":0.0,
            "oneYear":3.65,
            "eighteenMonths":0.0,
            "twoYears":3.59,
            "threeYears":3.99,
            "fourYears":4.35,
            "fiveYears":4.45,
            "sixYears":0.0,
            "revolvingCredit":0.0,
            "isSpecial":true
         },
         { 
            "bankName":"BNZ",
            "productName":"BNZ Investor Standard",
            "floating":5.55,
            "sixMonths":5.04,
            "oneYear":4.7,
            "eighteenMonths":4.8,
            "twoYears":4.6,
            "threeYears":4.8,
            "fourYears":5.2,
            "fiveYears":5.4,
            "sixYears":0.0,
            "revolvingCredit":0.0,
            "isSpecial":false
         },
         { 
            "bankName":"BNZ",
            "productName":"BNZ Investor Special",
            "floating":5.55,
            "sixMonths":6.3,
            "oneYear":3.9,
            "eighteenMonths":0.0,
            "twoYears":3.84,
            "threeYears":4.24,
            "fourYears":4.6,
            "fiveYears":4.7,
            "sixYears":0.0,
            "revolvingCredit":0.0,
            "isSpecial":false
         }
      ],
      "knownDiscount":[ 

      ],
      "type":[ 
         1,
         4
      ],
      "mortgageFeatures":{ 
         "welcomeHomeLoans":"No",
         "kiwiBuild":"Yes",
         "preApproval":"Up to 90 days",
         "interestOnly":"Yes",
         "redraw":"Yes",
         "revolvingCredit":"No",
         "amortisingRevolvingCredit":"Yes",
         "revolvingCreditMonthlyFee":"$2",
         "offset":"Yes",
         "ownerOccupiedLoanTerm":"30 years",
         "investmentPropertyLoanTerm":"30 years",
         "earlyRepayment":"Yes"
      },
      "url":"/banks/BNZ",
      "website":"https://www.bnz.co.nz/"
   },
```

I tried many times but it is only sorting the rates of each array, it does not sort all floating numbers. I want to sort floating property of array rates

Comment: Why are you calling `element.rates.sort()` twice?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're sorting the rates for each bank. Do you also want to sort the array of banks? Which rate should they be sorted by, since they each have an array of rates?

Comment: Oh , I am doing this

 let newArrayRates = [];
     newArrayRates = banksData;
     newArrayRates.forEach(element => {

       element.rates.sort(function(a, b) {
       
        let textA = a; 
        let textB = b;
 
        return textA.floating <
         textB.floating
         ? -1
         : textA.floating >
         textB.floating
         ? 1 
         : 0;
 
     
     
     // });
    
    })
     
    })
    this.banks = newArrayRates;

Comment: I want to sort array banksData based on floating ASC or DESC any way

Comment: But each bank has an array of rates, which one should it be sorted on?

Comment: Why do you need the `textA` and `textB` variables? You can just use `a.floating` and `b.floating`.

Comment: I am not able to sort the banksData based on floating so is there any way? Should i recontruct this array? or what could be the solution? This array has been defined by another developer . 

 I need to get this array sorted

Comment: You keep saying the same thing, I still don't understand it. What do you mean by "sort the banksData based on floating"?

Comment: Please show the expected output.  I can make no sense of this.  How would you sort these three values: `ANZ: [6.9, 2.0], ASB: [5.2, 5.0], BNZ: [5.3, 0.0, 5.55]`?  Are you looking to sort together the objects stored under `rate`?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quite clear.  Is this what you want?:

```js
const sortRatesByFloating = banks => banks .map (({rates, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest, 
  rates: rates .slice(0) .sort ((a, b, x = a .floating, y = b .floating) => x - y)
}))


const banksData=[{name:"ANZ2",rates:[{bankName:"ANZ",productName:"ANZ",floating:6.9,sixMonths:4.79,oneYear:4.15,eighteenMonths:4.49,twoYears:4.09,threeYears:4.49,fourYears:4.75,fiveYears:4.85,sixYears:0,revolvingCredit:5.8,isSpecial:!1},{bankName:"ANZ Bank",productName:"ANZ Special",floating:2,sixMonths:4.29,oneYear:3.65,eighteenMonths:3.99,twoYears:3.59,threeYears:3.99,fourYears:0,fiveYears:0,sixYears:0,revolvingCredit:0,isSpecial:!0}],knownDiscount:[],type:[1,4],mortgageFeatures:{welcomeHomeLoans:"No",kiwiBuild:"Yes",preApproval:"Up to 90 days",interestOnly:"Yes",redraw:"No",revolvingCredit:"Yes",amortisingRevolvingCredit:"No",revolvingCreditMonthlyFee:"$12.50",offset:"No",ownerOccupiedLoanTerm:"30 Years",investmentPropertyLoanTerm:"30 Years",earlyRepayment:"Yes"},url:"/banks/ANZ2",website:"https://www.anz.co.nz/personal/"},{name:"ASB ",rates:[{bankName:"ASB1",productName:"ASB",floating:5.2,sixMonths:4.79,oneYear:4.15,eighteenMonths:4.25,twoYears:4.09,threeYears:4.39,fourYears:4.69,fiveYears:4.79,sixYears:0,revolvingCredit:5.3,isSpecial:!1},{bankName:"ASB Bank",productName:"ASB Special",floating:5,sixMonths:4.29,oneYear:3.75,eighteenMonths:3.75,twoYears:3.59,threeYears:3.89,fourYears:4.19,fiveYears:4.29,sixYears:0,revolvingCredit:0,isSpecial:!0}],knownDiscount:[],type:[1,4],mortgageFeatures:{welcomeHomeLoans:"No",kiwiBuild:"Yes",preApproval:"Up to 90 days",interestOnly:"Yes",redraw:"No",revolvingCredit:"Yes",amortisingRevolvingCredit:"Yes",revolvingCreditMonthlyFee:"$12.00",offset:"No",ownerOccupiedLoanTerm:"30 years",investmentPropertyLoanTerm:"25 years",earlyRepayment:"Yes"},url:"/banks/ASB ",website:"https://www.asb.co.nz/"},{name:"BNZ",rates:[{bankName:"BNZ",productName:"BNZ Owner Occupied Standard",floating:5.3,sixMonths:4.79,oneYear:4.45,eighteenMonths:4.55,twoYears:4.35,threeYears:4.55,fourYears:4.95,fiveYears:5.15,sixYears:0,revolvingCredit:0,isSpecial:!1},{bankName:"BNZ",productName:"BNZ Owner Occupied Special",floating:0,sixMonths:0,oneYear:3.65,eighteenMonths:0,twoYears:3.59,threeYears:3.99,fourYears:4.35,fiveYears:4.45,sixYears:0,revolvingCredit:0,isSpecial:!0},{bankName:"BNZ",productName:"BNZ Investor Standard",floating:5.55,sixMonths:5.04,oneYear:4.7,eighteenMonths:4.8,twoYears:4.6,threeYears:4.8,fourYears:5.2,fiveYears:5.4,sixYears:0,revolvingCredit:0,isSpecial:!1},{bankName:"BNZ",productName:"BNZ Investor Special",floating:5.55,sixMonths:6.3,oneYear:3.9,eighteenMonths:0,twoYears:3.84,threeYears:4.24,fourYears:4.6,fiveYears:4.7,sixYears:0,revolvingCredit:0,isSpecial:!1}],knownDiscount:[],type:[1,4],mortgageFeatures:{welcomeHomeLoans:"No",kiwiBuild:"Yes",preApproval:"Up to 90 days",interestOnly:"Yes",redraw:"Yes",revolvingCredit:"No",amortisingRevolvingCredit:"Yes",revolvingCreditMonthlyFee:"$2",offset:"Yes",ownerOccupiedLoanTerm:"30 years",investmentPropertyLoanTerm:"30 years",earlyRepayment:"Yes"},url:"/banks/BNZ",website:"https://www.bnz.co.nz/"}];

console .log (sortRatesByFloating (banksData))
```

In this function, each bank's rates are sorted (ascending) by their `floating` property.  I do not modify the original structure, returning a fairly shallow copy with a new array of sorted rates.

Or did you want something different?

Comment: I have already achieved this, i am able to sort each bank's data, but i need all banks sorted with floating ASC or DESC

Comment: See my comment on the question.